# created a session in .ashx file and want to acces in .aspx page but i found the null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

i am creating a session in http handler and assign it some kind of value now i want to acces this value in .aspx page but there i found a null value of my session em new with this so i can,t handle this if any1 of u know the answer plz reply as soon as possible 
here is my .ashx code

```
public class login_handler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState,System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
    string MethodName = string.Empty;
    string CallBackMethodName = string.Empty;
    object Parameter = string.Empty;
    DbUser _DbUser = new DbUser();

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Write(check(context));
        context.Response.Redirect("project.aspx");
    }

    public string check(HttpContext context)
    {

        JsonResponse _response = new JsonResponse();
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer =
                     new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        try
        {
            User _U = new User();
            _U.email_address = context.Request.Params["email_address"].ToString();
            _U.password = context.Request.Params["password"].ToString();
            string company_name = string.Empty;
            int company_id;


            _response.IsSucess = true;
            _response.CallBack = CallBackMethodName;


            _response.ResponseData = _DbUser.check_user(_U);
            context.Session["company_id"] = _DbUser.check_company(_U);
            // in context.Session["company_id"] i got the value 10.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _response.Message = ex.Message;
            _response.IsSucess = false;
        }
        return jSearializer.Serialize(_response);
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

here is my .aspx code

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["company_id"] != null)
        {


            int a = (int)Session["company_id"];
        }
```

here if(Session[company_id] != null returns false 
kindly help me to know how can i get the value of session in this page

here is my web.config code

```
     <sessionState mode="InProc"  customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="junaidcrmConnectionString" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Sounds like you're using a bit of a hack currently, there may be a better way...

Comment: what does it mean in handler `context.Response.Redirect("project.aspx");`? And what do you want to achieve from this.

Comment: i want to access the value of session in another page that is project.aspx but i found null value there.

Comment: @AazanAbeer - `IReadOnlySessionState` and `context.Session["company_id"] = ...;`?

Comment: If my answer helped below, please mark.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this remove `IReadOnlySessionState`

```
public class login_handler : IHttpHandler,System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Session["mySession"]="ABC";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the cookieless attribute to your sesstionState in your web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc"  cookieless="true" />
```

If you remove the interface "IReadOnlySessionState" from your .ashx page your problem will be solved. I missed that before.